# Ambiguous mapping found when I use extends clause

Tags: java, spring-mvc, inheritance, annotations

I have a **CustomerController** and **CustomerCardController** classes that extend **CrudMethods** class.

I choose so, because these two controller use the same methods (getFileCustomer() is one of these). And I thought that it had been better use the inheritance to save code's rows.

**CustomerController**

```
@Controller
public class CustomerController extends CrudMethods {
...
```

**CustomerCardController**

```
@Controller
public class CustomerCardController extends CrudMethods{
...
```

**CrudMethos**

```
@Controller
public abstract class CrudMethods {

@RequestMapping("getFileCustomer")
@ResponseBody
public String getFileCustomer() {
...
```

When I run, GlassFish gives me that error:

> HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error   type Exception report
>
> message: Internal Server Error
>
> description: The server encountered an internal error that prevented
>   it     from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception:
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher
>   threw exception
>
> root cause: Ambiguous mapping found

The problems are @RequestMapping and @ResponseBody annotations.

In fact, if I remove them the application starts.

But I need of these annotation. Because, the @RequestMapping and @ResponseBody are used by Ajax call when the application runs.

And getFileCustomer() is used in both of controllers.

How can solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@RequestMapping("getFileCustomer")` this request mapping is present in both `CustomerCardController` and `CustomerController` class since they extend same class which has this mapping. So you have duplicate entry for same request mapping.

Comment: @DavideFruci You should put the `RequestMapping` annotated method in one your controllers, or in a new controller

Comment: I use override annotation and I solve the problem. Thanks a lot!